# How to convert stringified array to array in JavaScript when I don't have control over the source string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

So I have an array of items, surrounded with `""`, not `''` (if that makes a difference):

```
"['item 1', 'item2', 'item 3']"
```

I'd like to convert it to:

```
['item 1', 'item2', 'item 3']
```

I tried using JSON.parse() but this doesn't work (it says Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1). Not sure how to do this--thanks!

Comment: There's no standard method for parsing strings like that. Can you fix the sender to create valid JSON?

Comment: The array of items is an array of strings that's been stringified. So it started as ['string1','string2','string3'] but then was stringified so now it's "['string1','string2','string3']" and I'm trying to turn it back into ['string1','string2','string3']. @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero

Comment: @Barmar No...it's contained in a .csv file that can't be changed.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` won't create a string like that, so I don't know what you mean by "an array of strings that's been stringified".

Comment: This looks like it might have come from Python.

Comment: Don't you have it backwards when you wrote "surrounded with `""`, not `''`"?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `'` with `"` and parse the string.

```js
const
    string = "['item 1', 'item2', 'item 3']",
    array = JSON.parse(string.replace(/'/g, '"'));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Unless there are escaped quotes that shouldn't be replaced.....

Answer (score -1):

You could `eval` the string:

```js
const input = "['item 1', 'item2', 'item 3']";
const result = eval(input);
console.log(result);
```

**Warning:**
`eval` can execute arbitrary code in the argument passed to it. Do **not** use it if the input comes from an untrusted source (e.g., a user...).

Comment: @Kinglish I didn't downvote, but I guess the reason is `eval`. According to [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) you shouldn't use `eval`. `Function` is the better alternative and can achieve the same result.